# Convert INT to BIGINT in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, type-conversion, biginteger

SQL 2005, 600,000,000 rows.

I have a table called Location currently using the data type INT in identity PK column LocationID. I would like to attempt converting this data type to BIGINT.

The following script I think should help to allow inserted into the PK column but i am unsure how to progress form here.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT LOCATION ON /*allows insert into the identity column*/`

SET IDENTITY_INSERT LOCATION OFF /*Returns the identity column to initial state*/`
```

Location table create script below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [LocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JourneyID] [int] NULL,
    [DeviceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PacketTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [PacketStatusID] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Location_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LocationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Device_Location_FK1] FOREIGN KEY([DeviceID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Device] ([DeviceID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Device_Location_FK1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [PacketStatus_Location_FK1] FOREIGN KEY([PacketStatusID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PacketStatus] ([PacketStatusID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location] CHECK CONSTRAINT [PacketStatus_Location_FK1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [PacketType_Location_FK1] FOREIGN KEY([PacketTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PacketType] ([PacketTypeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location] CHECK CONSTRAINT [PacketType_Location_FK1]
```

One option i think would be to copy the data to a new table then delete the old table and rename the new one however we have constraints that will need to be dropped for this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea of a new table is the way to go.

On a development server, you can see the script that SSMS would produce if you change the data type using the table designer. It is a good start. This will add triggers and constraints back afterwards.

A tool like Red gate SQL Compare also allows you to check that everything was created OK

Comment: Thanks for the reply .... was not sure what you meant. This article: http://lisazhou.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/sql-server-generate-change-script-from-table-design-view/ explained. However , when attempting to SAVE TEXT FILE upon selecting the script option i see: Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you have mad require the following tables to be dropped and re-created. You have either made changes to a table that can’t be re-created or enabled the option Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created. Resulting file contains no script that would produce the amendment.

Comment: Sorry , i understand , drop the CONSTRAINTS first before changing the datatype , can see SCRIPT now. Thats helpful thank you.